Did any Vedic kings(Ramayana Mahabharata Age) rule directly over mlecchas?
I know that Kings Mandhatri Yayati Bharata etc conquered entire world but did they also administer it..My question is can Aryan kings rule over land of mlecchas? Is there any scriptural example of this?
Kindly answer

We have references from Bhagavad Puran that Maharaj Prithu ruled over the whole world, maybe that included Mlecchas
